# SQL query to isolate an id on a many to many join table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a table that connects two other tables based on their ids. This a used to create a many to many relationship. The three tables are as follows.

`Table 1
table_1_id
name
...`

`Join Table
table_1_Id
table_2_Id`

`Table 2
table_2_id
data
...`

Say the join table has the following data for table_1_id's and table_2_ids

`1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 2
2, 3
3, 3`

I am given a collection of table_2_id's and I need to find which table_1_id has exactly those table_2_ids's. for instance. If the table 2 ids i'm given is (2, 3), then the id I want to grab would be 2. If I was given the collection (1, 2, 3), then the id I would need is 1. Note that (2, 3) would not return the table_1_id of 1, because even though it has both of those relationships, it doesn't have exactly those relationships only.

What would be the sql query to accomplish this?

Comment: So you mean to say `table_2_id = table_1_id`?

Comment: no, i'm not quite sure what you mean here but. I was only using psuedo id's to make things easier to understand. if it helps, just add 10 to all the table 2 id's so they are completely different than the table_1_ids.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see that you can do this--in your current DB structure--is by counting the numbers of rows that are returned and match that against the number of IDs that you search for. For example:

```
SELECT table_1_id, COUNT( table_1_id ) 
FROM  `join_table` 
WHERE table_2_id
IN ( 2, 3 ) 
GROUP BY table_1_id
```

This query will require you to evaluate the return outside of MySQL (i.e. PHP/ ASP), but I think it can be rewritten to work inside MySQL if that's absolutely necessary.

Comment: this was the direction I was thinking of too. but it doesn't work. the results of this would be (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1). so it looks like both id 1 and id 2 have a count of 2.

Comment: @JohnBaker Is it possible to rearrange your table structure to have a CSV column so your query can look like this: `SELECT table_1_id WHERE ids = '2,3'`?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT table_1_id FROM (
  SELECT table_1_id, GROUP_CONCAT(table_2_id) AS all_t2_ids
  FROM join_table
  WHERE table_2_id IN (2,3)
) Q 
WHERE all_t2_ids = '2,3'
```